# Flatten a hierarchy query PLSQL not using subqueries and functions

Tags: oracle, plsql, hierarchy

I am new to PLSQL and started learning how to write queries in efficient way. I have a challenge in front of me on flattening the employee reporting hierarchy using Connect By.

1. Currently, we have five levels of hierarchy in employee reporting but our query should not limit to 5 levels. In future, if we have new lvel of reporting the same query should work without making any changes.
2. All records in result set should ends at same level, If Manager has no reporting employee to him/her then level 5 should be manager itself. You can see below expected result for better understanding. example: Mgr1 and Mgr3

Note: for better performance, I dont want to use any functions or sub queries for this request.

Expected result:

```
Level 1     Level 2     Level 3 Level 4 Level 5 **(Level 6, Level 7 ) for future**
----------  ----------  ------- ------- ------ ------ -------
President   VP1         Dir1    Mgr1    Mgr1        
President   VP1         Dir2    Mgr2    Emp1        
President   VP2         Dir3    Mgr4    Emp2        
President   VP2         Dir4    Mgr3    Mgr3        
President   VP3         Dir5    Mgr5    Emp3        
President   VP3         Dir6    Mgr6    Emp4        
President   VP4         Dir7    Mgr7    Emp5
```

Comment: Your example isn't very clear, it would help if it was formatted and aligned properly, and showed the source data too. Why PL/SQL if you want to use-connect-by? And why are level 6/7 there but empty - by your earlier logic, shouldn't level 6 and 7 entries for the first row both be Mgr1 too?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, will work on it and try to improve the formatting, we have to solve this using Connect By not limited to PL/SQL , I just kept those two levels(level 6 and level 7 ) for understanding, in future Emp5 may have a reportee who goes into level 6 and so on.. even in that case our query should work.

Comment: And then all the other rows in the result set should have their level 5 value repeated as level 6?

Comment: If we have at least one employee in level 6 then we have to repeat all other records as level 5, if we don't have any employee in level 6 we should stop in level 5 only. in my example result set it should with level 5 but in future if we have any level 6 employee the same query should work
Thanks

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include sample input data that reflects the output you're expecting to get?

Comment: Writing the CONNECT BY query is simple (this site is [awash with examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+%22connect+by%22) as is [the Oracle SQL reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)). However, the requirement to default the dangling leaves is really tough, and I don't see how you could do it without either functions or subqueries. So, is that an actual requirement of your homework or just an extra limitation you're applying on yourself?

Comment: Thank YOU @APC for editing my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the following looks like the one you wanted:

```
with normalized$(super_id, emp_id) as (
    select null, 'president' from dual
    union all
    select 'president', 'vp1' from dual
    union all
    select 'president', 'vp2' from dual
    union all
    select 'president', 'vp3' from dual
    union all
    select 'president', 'vp4' from dual
    union all
    select 'vp1', 'dir1' from dual
    union all
    select 'vp1', 'dir2' from dual
    union all
    select 'vp2', 'dir3' from dual
    union all
    select 'vp2', 'dir4' from dual
    union all
    select 'vp3', 'dir5' from dual
    union all
    select 'vp3', 'dir6' from dual
    union all
    select 'vp4', 'dir7' from dual
    union all
    select 'dir1', 'mgr1' from dual
    union all
    select 'dir2', 'mgr2' from dual
    union all
    select 'dir3', 'mgr4' from dual
    union all
    select 'dir4', 'mgr3' from dual
    union all
    select 'dir5', 'mgr5' from dual
    union all
    select 'dir6', 'mgr6' from dual
    union all
    select 'dir7', 'mgr7' from dual
    union all
    select 'mgr2', 'emp1' from dual
    union all
    select 'mgr4', 'emp2' from dual
    union all
    select 'mgr5', 'emp3' from dual
    union all
    select 'mgr6', 'emp4' from dual
    union all
    select 'mgr7', 'emp5' from dual
    union all
    -- note: these two are added here for testing the levels 6 and 7
    select 'emp2', 'sub1' from dual
    union all
    select 'sub1', 'subsub1' from dual
),
denormalized$ as (
    select ora_hash(emp_id) as hierarchy_id, -- note: this is just "some" row id; use whatever else you wish
        sys_connect_by_path(emp_id, '|') as hierarchy
    from normalized$ N
    where connect_by_isleaf = 1
    start with super_id is null
    connect by prior emp_id = super_id
),
split$ as (
    select hierarchy_id,
        regexp_substr(hierarchy, '\|([^|]*)', 1, 1, null, 1) as h_lvl_1,
        regexp_substr(hierarchy, '\|([^|]*)', 1, 2, null, 1) as h_lvl_2,
        regexp_substr(hierarchy, '\|([^|]*)', 1, 3, null, 1) as h_lvl_3,
        regexp_substr(hierarchy, '\|([^|]*)', 1, 4, null, 1) as h_lvl_4,
        regexp_substr(hierarchy, '\|([^|]*)', 1, 5, null, 1) as h_lvl_5,
        regexp_substr(hierarchy, '\|([^|]*)', 1, 6, null, 1) as h_lvl_6,
        regexp_substr(hierarchy, '\|([^|]*)', 1, 7, null, 1) as h_lvl_7
    from denormalized$
),
filled$ as (
    select hierarchy_id,
        h_lvl_1,
        coalesce(h_lvl_2, h_lvl_1) as h_lvl_2,
        coalesce(h_lvl_3, h_lvl_2, h_lvl_1) as h_lvl_3,
        coalesce(h_lvl_4, h_lvl_3, h_lvl_2, h_lvl_1) as h_lvl_4,
        coalesce(h_lvl_5, h_lvl_4, h_lvl_3, h_lvl_2, h_lvl_1) as h_lvl_5,
        coalesce(h_lvl_6, h_lvl_5, h_lvl_4, h_lvl_3, h_lvl_2, h_lvl_1) as h_lvl_6,
        coalesce(h_lvl_7, h_lvl_6, h_lvl_5, h_lvl_4, h_lvl_3, h_lvl_2, h_lvl_1) as h_lvl_7
    from split$
)
select *
from filled$
;
```

... yielding...

```
HIERARCHY_ID H_LVL_1   H_LVL_2 H_LVL_3 H_LVL_4 H_LVL_5 H_LVL_6 H_LVL_7
------------ --------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
   490409852 president vp1     dir1    mgr1    mgr1    mgr1    mgr1
  1220769441 president vp1     dir2    mgr2    emp1    emp1    emp1
   849214331 president vp2     dir3    mgr4    emp2    sub1    subsub1
   530886880 president vp2     dir4    mgr3    mgr3    mgr3    mgr3
  1157603336 president vp3     dir5    mgr5    emp3    emp3    emp3
  1467614544 president vp3     dir6    mgr6    emp4    emp4    emp4
   523144703 president vp4     dir7    mgr7    emp5    emp5    emp5
```

**However**, there's no way (I know of) you could (without a table function returning `sys.anyDataSet`) possibly make a query to return arbitrary number of columns, so let's just stick to some presumed maximum number of levels in your hierarchy, in the case of the query above it being 7.

**Note** that the connect-by-path joining and its subsequent splitting can be done different ways - even without the relatively slow regular expressions. Inspect your own ways, choose what's best for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this